# How to display text on header image in an aesthetically pleasing way

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to create a website. On the home page, I am using a carousel slider in the header to display different images. On the images, there is a title, subtitle, and button. I wanted to ask if there was a better way to display the text and button so it doesn't cover up the images important parts of the image. I feel like the CSS I added to the picture is cutting too much of the picture off so it doesn't allow me to move the text and button around.

#### Note

If you can't see any text in the code snippet that's because the text is white.

### Test.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->

<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white py-3">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="/index.html">
            <img src="./assets/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
          </a>
  
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggler"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navmenu"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
          </button>
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
  
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            Services
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
            <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
            
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
        </div>
      
      </nav>
      <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->
  
      <!-- SHOWCASE START -->
      <section>
        <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="6" aria-label="Slide 7"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="7" aria-label="Slide 8"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
            <img src="./assets/networking-connections-004.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/cctv.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/datacenter-002 - Copy.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/digital-signage-005.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/general-support-001.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/net-support.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/pos.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/telecom.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
          </div> 
        
      </section>
      <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->

  </body>
</html>
```

### Test.css

```css
body {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.c-item {
    height: 480px;
}

.c-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}
```

```css
body {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.c-item {
    height: 480px;
}

.c-img {
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->

<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white py-3">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="/index.html">
            <img src="./assets/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
          </a>
  
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggler"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navmenu"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
          </button>
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
  
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            Services
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
            <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
            
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
        </div>
      
      </nav>
      <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->
  
      <!-- SHOWCASE START -->
      <section>
        <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="6" aria-label="Slide 7"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide-to="7" aria-label="Slide 8"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
            <img src="./assets/networking-connections-004.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/cctv.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/datacenter-002 - Copy.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/digital-signage-005.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/general-support-001.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/net-support.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/pos.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img src="./assets/telecom.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption top-0 mt-4">
              <p class="mt-5 text-uppercase">Get your unique solution</p>
              <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize>Project Name_____">Project Name_____</h1>
              <button class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 mt-5">Submit a Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#herocarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
          </div> 
        
      </section>
      <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->

  </body>
</html>
```